# page has to be refresh to show updated data in react?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have a form with two input fields

```
 <form method="POST" onSubmit={bnkSubmit}>
        <input type="text"  name="bnk" autoComplete="off" />
          <input type="text"  name="ifsc" autoComplete="off" />&nbsp;
           <input type="submit" value="Add" />
   </form>
```

data gets saved in the database but the problem is I have to refresh the page to get updated data

```
const bnkSubmit = async (e) =>{

    e.preventDefault()
    
    const {bnk, ifsc, user} = bank

    const res = await fetch('/addDetails', {

        method:"POST",
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
  
            bnk, ifsc, user
            
          })
    })

    const data = await res.json()

    if(res.status === 402 || !data)
    {
        alert("Please fill all details")

    }else{

        alert("Bank details added sucesfully")
        setbank({...bank, bnk:"", ifsc:""})
        e.target.reset()
       
    }

}
```

what I want is to update my table without refreshing the page where I'm showing the updated data.

```
 {resData.map((resData)=> 
                        <tr>
                            <td>{resData.acc_no}</td>
                            <td>{resData.ifsc}</td>
                            <td><button>Edit</button></td>
                            <td><button>Delete</button></td>
                        </tr>
                        )}
```

Comment: setbank({...bank, bnk:"", ifsc:""}) should update table automatically, is it not being updated after you submit?

Comment: how are you displaying your data in your table? Can you share the code?

Comment: @Albab I have updated the code please check.

Comment: Since you're mapping resData, you should also set it with the data in your code. According to your code, you're only setting the bank state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `useState` hook. You should also have `resData` as state as well. Or please share snippet of how you are managing `resData`.

```
  const [bank, setbank] = useState({ bnk: "", ifsc: "" })
  const [resData, setData] = useState([])
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are trying to map resData for displaying table data but in your code i can't see you are setting state for resData.

for updating table without refreshing page you need to set data in State for re-render .

//Declare initial state
const [resData, setresData] = useState([]);

//set state for resData
setresData(data);